# binary search in a relational database

Tags: database, query-optimization

I have a relation employee(employee_id, fisrtname, lastname, salary, department_id). If I want to execute a query using binary search and the query is like :

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE salary> 10000
AND department_id = 60
```

Should I have index on either of salary and department_id or on both of them to have the lowest cost(the minimum number of blocks read in a disk)?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't "do a binary search". You give the database information (i.e. indices) and let it do whatever it does. In this case you might consider an index on `(department_id, salary)` - this way the left-part of the index can "shrink" the search space quickly. However, if the department_id is not qualified, then you'd need an index on `(salary,..)` for it to be used in the query planner. As far as to see which is "best" or what is "actually done", ask the query planner for the used execution plan. (Too many/unnecessary indices can be as bad as too few.)

Comment: _Possibly_ by 'binary search' you mean a 'clustered index' search...which is an ordered index that the database can search in a tree-like fashion (get to the target leaf-node traversing the minimal number of branches/pages). However a table (at least Sql Server) can have only one clustered index, and _usually_ clustered indexes are reserved for the primary key or or a unique attribute...so you would **not** put a clustered index on salary and dept_id, it would be a non-clustered index as the previous comment suggests.

Answer (score 2):

For your query, the best index is `employee(department_id, salary)`.

This is a composite index.  It is important that the columns be in this order, because `department_id` has an equality comparison and `salary` an inequality.

How this is implemented is not really relevant.  Most database would store such an index as a b-tree, which would result in a "binary" search.  However, databases can take advantage of multiple processors and multiple disks.